# Is this a rigorous enough argument against uniform convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, convergence-divergence

I have $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{ln(1+x/n)}{n}$ and I need to prove that it does not converge uniformly on $[0,\infty)$.

So I use the delta-epsilon definition of convergence and then I expand this inequality:

$$|f_{m+1} + ... + f_n| \leq ... \leq \frac{x(n-m-1)}{N^2}$$

So we see that $N$ is necessarily a function of $x$ which is enough to show that uniform convergence is not possible.

My problem with this is, the inequalities. They seem arbitrary. One could simplify in a different manner and maybe end up with a $N$ that is constant.

Could one maybe just say, the $|f_{m+1} + ... + f_n|\to \infty$ as $x\to\infty$ and therefore, no matter what $N$ one choose eventually the sum will be larger than epsilon?

Comment: You seem to have found a bound for the left hand side of the inequality and to be trying to say that because the the bound is large and depends on x then convergence is not uniform. That is not correct. Something more is required. For example, you could prove that the bound is th ebest possible bound, say.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Yes that's exactly what I was worried about. I don't think trying to find the least upper bound is possible. What do you think of my second method: Could one maybe just say, the |fm+1+...+fn|→∞ as x→∞ and therefore, no matter what N one choose eventually the sum will be larger than epsilon?

Comment: Well, the normal way to do what you want is to prove a **lower** bound on the sum. An infinite limit can be used to obtain one.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Cannot I just use contradiction? All I need is to show that for one epsilon and any given N there is an x that such that |fm+1+...+fn| > $\epsilon$. That is also mathematically correct right?

Comment: A contradiction with what? That looks like a direct aargument showing that the sequence does not converge uniformly.